# How can I solve this limit: $\lim_{n\to \infty } \left(\frac{1}{1+n} + \frac{1}{2+n} + ... + \frac{1}{2n} \right) $?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

how can I solve this?

$$\lim_{n\to \infty } \left(\frac{1}{1+n} + \frac{1}{2+n} + ... + \frac{1}{2n}  \right) $$

but the limit of this?

$$(x_n) = \frac{1}{\ln(n^2)} + \frac{1}{\ln(n^3)} + ... + \frac{1}{\ln(n^n)} $$

At the second sequence I tried  this:

$$ (x_n) = \frac{1}{\ln(n)}\Bigl(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + ... + \frac{1}{n}\Bigr)$$
That is indetermination $ 0\cdot \infty$ since the sum diverges, but I don't know
how to continue.

Comment: You're asking two questions in one. We generally prefer question posts to focus on a single question. Also, what have you tried? What tools for limit calculations do you have at your disposal? What's stopping you from applying them?

Comment: By the way, [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/) is really useful to find old questions on this site. That's how I found the duplicate I mentioned in my first comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will use the following fact.

> **Lemma.** There is a real number $\gamma$ such that
>   $$
> \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(H_n-\ln n\right) = \gamma,
> $$
>   where $H_n=1+\frac{1}{2}+\ldots+\frac{1}{n}$ is a $n$-th harmonic number.

Now, it's clear that
$$
\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+\ldots+\frac{1}{2n}=H_{2n}-H_n.
$$
Hence,
$$
\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+\ldots+\frac{1}{2n}\right)=
\\
\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(H_{2n}-H_n\right)=
\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}(H_{2n}-\ln (2n))-\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}(H_n-\ln n) + \ln 2 = \gamma-\gamma+\ln 2 = \ln 2.
$$

For the second one note that from the lemma we obtain that 
$$
\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{H_n-\ln n}{\ln n} = 0,~\text{so}~\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{H_n}{\ln n} = 1.
$$
Thus, 
$$
\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{2}+\ldots+\frac{1}{n}}{\ln n} = \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{H_n-1}{\ln n} = 1.
$$

Comment: Why do you do so complicated for such an easy exercice ? (-1)

Comment: Because I wanted to avoid using properties of integrals. This solution uses only sequence limits. The main lemma follows from convergence of decreasing and bounded sequence.